# gmdate() equivalent for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp, sql-update

i'm trying to update some big table in this way:

```
<?php
   $tables = array("table1","table2","table3","table4","table5");
   foreach ($tables as $table) {
      $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $data = $row['data'];
        $data = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data));
        mysql_query("UPDATE {$table} SET data='$data' WHERE user_id='".$row['user_id']."'";);
      }     
   }
?>
```

Every tables have about 80.000 rows and process will take too much time to finish. How can i solve this using an equivalent function of `gmdate` in mysql? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use mysql's STR_TO_DATE function to update, use this function in update query. try this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Fri, 23 Nov 2012 10:00:27 +0000", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s +0000");
```

use output ot STR_TO_DATE and put it in the format you needed.

you can use following single update query

```
mysql_query('UPDATE {$table} SET data= STR_TO_DATE(YOURDATACOLUMN, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s +0000"); WHERE user_id="'.$row['user_id'].'"';);
```

Comment: how can i use that function? can u show me an example? my data in row['data'] is like : "Fri, 23 Nov 2012 10:00:27 +0000" and i need to convert to a date field

Comment: the execution time is now reduced by 100.000 times.. u r great! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `select DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(),'%Y-%m-%d')` to show the current date in Y-m-d format.